# Modified version of an object, use of articles

Tags: grammaticality, articles

What article should I use when referring to a modified version of an object?

For example, I try to shorten *"a modified version of Dijkstra's algorithm"* and I'm not sure which of the following are correct:

1. I intend to use **the** modified Dijkstra's algorithm.
2. I intend to use **a** modified Dijkstra's algorithm.
3. I intend to use modified Dijkstra's algorithm.

I googled these and there does not seem to be a consensus: 1980 results for [the](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22the+modified+dijkstra%27s+algorithm%22),
1710 results for [a](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22a+modified+dijkstra%27s+algorithm%22). Do the usual rules for using articles apply here?

Comment: The raw Google results will mask whether this is a subsequent mention in an article say. (And is there a second (etc) modified version, or is there a possibility that one will be developed?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of "the" as opposed to "a" is dependent on the ambiguity surrounding the modified object. Is it a version which has already been defined? If so, "the" is correct. If not, "a" is correct.

For example, in your included Google searches there is a paper that uses both "the" and "a": http://jwcn.eurasipjournals.com/content/pdf/1687-1499-2014-90.pdf

Notice in the title when the specifics of the algorithm are uncertain "a" is used. Later on, when the exact algorithm is understood, "the" is used.